# How to update applications downloaded from internet and installed?

Tags: package-management

For updating packages installed via repositories we simply type in terminal

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
```

Also in case of packages such as **Google Chrome** while installation the repository gets installed automatically.

But in case of packages which are downloaded from the internet and installed but there are no repositories of them in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

how do we update them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those cases where you installed .deb Packages outside of any repositories located in `/etc/apt/sources.list**` you are in fact the one responsible for updating them.

Just keep an eye on new releases (I do so by subscribing to the project's blog's rss feed for example) and when a new version was released, you just repeat the steps you took on initial installation of the .deb package:

1. download the .deb from the project's website
2. install it by either

   - clicking on it in your webbrowser to install it using the software center
   - or by running `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/<filename>.deb`

In some cases there is a PPA on launchpad which does provide community-provided packages and more or less regular updates. Though you really should double-check if the author of those packages has enough credibility to install their packages on your system.